# Is it possible to create a .bak file via SQL Server Management Studio on Azure cloud hosting?

Tags: sql-server, azure, backup, database-backups

I need to create a `.bak` backup file of my SQL Server database on Azure hosting, because that's the only method which my new hosting supports for restoring a database.

Is this even possible to do? In SQL Server Management Studio, there is no "Backup" option under "Tasks" when I right-click on my database. The SQL Server edition is Standard, not Express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create `.bak` files in Azure DB. You will need to perform below steps at a high level to get a `.BAK` file

1. Create a `.bacpac` file for database in Azure
2. Import that `.bacpac` file to Local SQL Server and restore it
3. Now you can create a `.Bak` file on local SQL Server